# How can I apply styles from class definitions to all child divs except the last one?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'd like to apply two class definitions to all child divs except for the last one using Sass. This is what I had in mind, but it's not working:

```css
.all-but-last {
  :not(:last-child) {
    .border-grey-light;
    .b-border;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='all-but-last'>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: If `all-but-last` are the elements you want to address, then I don't see anything wrong here

Comment: Looked fine to me too - perhaps the classes I am trying to apply are not yet defined. I will inspect the load order of my scss files more closely

Comment: You can also use :nth-last-child(n+1)

Comment: @TylerH close, there is no mention of the proper application of '@extend'

Answer (score 2):

```
.all-but-last {
  :not(:last-child) {
    .border-grey-light;
    .b-border;
  }
}
```

This above syntax is invalid. Here is the correction

```
.all-but-last {
  :not(:last-child) {
    @extend .border-grey-light;
    @extend .b-border;
  }
}
```

In order for this to work, you must import the file(s) that contain the class definition(s) you wish to extend. I didn't need to use `&` to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a CSS preprocessor, the code you wrote is OK. However you're missing `&` if you are using `LESS`. So try this:

```
.all-but-last {
  &:not(:last-child) {
    .border-grey-light;
    .b-border;
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like OP is using SASS. In the case of SASS, this answer means `.all-but-last:not(:last-child)` instead of `.all-but-last div:not(:last-child)`.

Comment: @J.Titus there is no difference for using `&` for nested rules between `SASS` and `LESS`, see here http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#nested_rules

Comment: LESS is a CSS preprocessor.